# How can I use tasks in VS Code to run 3 different commands in three different terminals?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I want to use tasks in VS Code to run the following three commands in three different integrated VS Code terminals:

```
flask run -p 3003

celery -A kreoh_worker.celery worker -l info

docker run -p 6379:6379 -it redis/redis-stack:latest
```

The task runs the flask server, then waits for it it to terminate, it doesn't, then the two other commands fail to excecute.

GPT4 gave up on this problem.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Run Development Server",
        "type": "shell",
        "isBackground": true,
        "command": "source /Users/davidmcsharry/Documents/soBack/venv/bin/activate && flask run -p 3003",
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "presentation": {
          "echo": true,
          "reveal": "always",
          "focus": false,
          "panel": "new"
        }
      },
      {
        "label": "Run Celery Worker",
        "type": "shell",
        "isBackground": true,
        "command": "source /Users/davidmcsharry/Documents/soBack/venv/bin/activate && celery -A kreoh_worker.celery worker -l info",
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "presentation": {
          "echo": true,
          "reveal": "always",
          "focus": false,
          "panel": "new"
        }
      },
      {
        "label": "Run Redis",
        "type": "shell",
        "isBackground": true,
        "command": "docker run -p 6379:6379 -it redis/redis-stack:latest",
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "presentation": {
          "echo": true,
          "reveal": "always",
          "focus": false,
          "panel": "new"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is the task that failed to run the latter two commands.

Comment: Can you run the tasks successfully outside of VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [compound tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks) with `"dependsOrder": "parallel"` (or if you actually want them to run sequentially, with each one waiting on the previous to finish before beginning, use `"sequence"`). Ex.

```json
{
   "label": "My Task 1",
   "type": "shell",
   "command": "echo Hello",
   "problemMatcher": []
},
{
   "label": "My Task 2",
   "type": "shell",
   "command": "echo Hello",
   "problemMatcher": []
},
{
   "label": "My Task 3",
   "type": "shell",
   "command": "echo Hello",
   "problemMatcher": []
},
{
   "label": "My Tasks",
   "type": "shell",
   "dependsOn": ["My Task 1", "My Task 2", "My Task 3"],
   "dependsOrder": "parallel",
},
```